# Installing XCode 3.2.6 but no Xcode app in the Applications folder

Tags: iphone, xcode

I just installed Xcode 3.2.6 a couple times in a custom directory. I am installing that in addition to Xcode 4.2 that is installed in my developer folder. I can't seem to find the Xcode app in the Applications folder in the custom directory. All I see is a Utilities folder. Any ideas as to what might have happened?

Comment: My Xcode 4.0 installer moved the 3.2 to /Developer-old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things to keep in mind:

1. If you are going to have multiple versions of Xcode installed, you MUST install them in order from lowest to highest version number, or you will break ALL of them. For example, if you installed Xcode4 and then Xcode3, neither is likely to work. The reason for this is that part of the Xcode install includes stuff that can only be placed in shared directories -- directories shared by all instances of Xcode. Installing an older version of these files over a newer version breaks 'em all. (I just went through this pain, by accident!)
2. If you install into a custom directory, the Xcode binary WILL be in the Applications folder in that custom directory. The default directory that Xcode installs to (if you don't change it) is /Developer, of course, but you can change this when you are doing an install to say, /Xcode4 or whatever you like. That being said, Spotlight Search is certainly a good first step to locating stuff you just cannot find by hand. :-)

Comment: Oh. Damn. Xcode 4 seemed to be working fine. Do you think its better to reinstall 4 as well?

Comment: Well, if it seems to be working, even after installing a previous version, then it's probably ok. When I said "broken"  meant: Xcode won't launch.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the very same problem.

uninstalled version 3.2.6 using the uninstall --all method via terminal (described in documentation).
then re-installed 4.2 version, then uninstalled, using terminal,

then re-installed 3.2.6 |===>  now running smoothly.
might see what happens if i add 4.2 in a different directory later.

Answer (score 0):

Just use search function in finder dude.

Anyway, default location for Xcode installation is under Macindosh HD\Developer\Applications
If you didn't change the path during installation, you should be able to find it there

Comment: You're using Windows-style path separator \ to describe a location on a Mac?!?

Comment: I knew that. I had changed the install directory. I could find Xcode 4 but not 3.

Comment: @Richard, thanks for pointing. Actual Path should be /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app